# How to get a column name based on function

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a dataset:

```
A B C Final
1 2 3 C
4 5 6 C
```

I want final to return the column name of the max value. In the example above, 3 and 6 are the highest values, so columns C will be returned in the 'Final' column.Is there an efficient way/formula you can use to get the column names without using VBA? the real dataset containts 60 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to get the column letter.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(MAX(A3:C3),A3:C3,0),4),1,"")
```

If you want the header, I think there's an easier way, but the extension from this would be

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(MAX(A3:C3),A3:C3,0),4),1,"")&1)
```

For the header, the better way

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,1,MATCH(MAX(A3:C3),A3:C3,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

HLOOKUP is a way without VBA, but sadly HLOOKUP does only search in the first row of the array, so you should add the "title column" at the bottom

```
A B C Final
1 2 3 <formula1>
4 5 6 <formula2>
A B C
```

If the dataset starts at first corner, Formula1 would be :

```
=HLOOKUP(MAX(A2:C2);A2:C4;2;FALSE)
```

Formula2 will be

```
=HLOOKUP(MAX(A3:C3);A3:C4;1;FALSE)
```

etc...

```
=HLOOKUP(MAX($A3:$C3);$A3:$C$4;<manual change here backward>;FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vector form of the `LOOKUP` function.

If your first row, with A B C, are the labels, then:

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/(MAX(A2:C2)=A2:C2),$A$1:$C$1)
```